# CollectionView strange behavior when reusing cells

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview

I am using a custom collectionview cell which has a variable called views.
For some reason i get the views in the wrong cell and it also sometimes duplicates itself.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: docCellId, for: indexPath) as! DocumentCell
    cell.backgroundColor = .white
    cell.indexPath = indexPath
    cell.views = dic[indexPath] ?? [(UIView(),CGRect.zero)]
    cell.label.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
    return cell
}
```

> This is in my custom collectionview cell

```
var views : [(UIView, CGRect)] = [] {
    didSet {
         addViews()
    }
}

fileprivate func addViews() {
    for i in views {
        addSubview(i.0)
        i.0.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, paddingTop: i.1.origin.y, paddingLeft: i.1.origin.x, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you reuse your cell you should override `prepareForReuse()` and remove the previously added views otherwise you just will add the views on top of the existing views.

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
        views.forEach { $0.0.removeFromSuperview() }
        views = []
    }
```

Regards